# How to prevent duplicate entry for a given foreign key in existing table in ms sql server.?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

OrderId is primary key and StoreID is foreign key.

I want output like that

| OrderId | StoreID |
| --- | --- |
| 453626266223 | 3 |
| 453626266223 | 4 |
| 129874561234 | 3 |

Comment: add a unique constraint to the table

Comment: `OrderId` is NOT a primary key.  It is obviously duplicated.  Your question makes not sense.

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like a modelling problem.  A Foreign Key references unique values in the related table - should they also really be unique values in the referencing table?

That implies a 1-1 relationship between the values ... should they be split to different tables or can they stay in a single table?

If the model is correct and you do need to separate them to different tables while maintaining a 1-1 relationship then add a UNIQUE CONSTRAINT to the column in the referencing table.